# Apache Environment Variables in MOD rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, env

IN my httpd.conf I am setting a variable

```
SetEnv MY_URL_WWW       "http://myURLtowhatever.com"
```

And in my .htaccess, i have a rewrite rule, where i want to redirect to my ENV url

```
RewriteRule ^redirect$ %{ENV:MY_URL_WWW} [L,NC,R=301,QSA]
```

This is not working, and i really want it to, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You must set it with `RewriteRule`. Try this:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=MY_URL_WWW:http://myURLtowhatever.com]
```

PS: you can enable the `mod_rewrite` log with `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` to see what happen.

Comment: so the environment variables in the apache config are not exactly the same environment variables that the mod_rewrite module uses?

Comment: The environment variables set by `SetEnv` directive are set the last after early request processing (such as `RewriteRule`) are run. 

Have a look at: [mod_env](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) and [SetEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/env.html) directive.

Comment: Ah, good to know.